# Multi threaded game - updating, rendering, and how to split them

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

So, I'm working on a game engine, and I've made pretty good progress. However, my engine is single-threaded, and the advantages of splitting updating and rendering into separate threads sounds like a very good idea.

How should I do this? Single threaded game engines are (conceptually) very easy to make, you have a loop where you update -> render -> sleep -> repeat. However, I can't think of a good way to break updating and rendering apart, especially if I change their update rates (say I go through the update loop 25x a second, and have 60fps for rendering) - what if I begin updating halfway through a render loop, or vice versa?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place your update logic in some kind of `Updater` worker class (implementing `Runnable`), and put renderer into separate worker class. When you need to update data, let Updater put that update into queue shared by both Updater and Producer. Most convenient would be to use queue which already have built-in multi-threaded support, like subclass of `BlockingQueue`. For example code, see javadoc for `BlockingQueue`.

Using queue is natural if you need to render all changes, even obsolete ones. If you wish to render only the latest change, use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of queue.

Don't forget to make your updates immutable objects, so there's no chance update can change while you render it.

As Nirmal pointed out, you could use some kind of thread pool to limit number of threads and to simplify starting/stopping of threads. Refer to `Executor` interface and `Executors` utility class in JDK to see available options here.

Comment: Do they need to be immutable? That sounds like I need to progressively copy what to render into some sort of "Frame" object. Is that the most efficient way?

Comment: It's not the most efficient way memory-wise, of course. But it's most simple to develop and understand in multi-threaded environment. If your objects can't change, you won't need to worry about changing them properly in concurrent threads -- this is greatly enhance simplicity and maintainability of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going pipeline with this architecture, meaning that the render stage will render all the elements updated on the previous frame, it would go like this:

Update 0

Update 1 Render 0

Update 2 Render 1

Update 3 Render 2

....

it would mean that your game will use more memory and all the objects will have to have per frame states / data

if you introduce more layers in this pipeline your game will suffer from input lag (meaning the user will see his action on the screen later then normal), so I suggest to using just this 2 stage pipeline

Answer (score 0):

create `pojo` for every category, one runnable object contains data like fps rate, UI screen class n all requited information, you can make common information singleton, so at every time rendering start thread for updating, i recommend threadpool to keep memory consumption limited

Answer (score 0):

Also note that your draw thread should never run faster then your update thread. Since if your update thread is not done with the current step yet, you will draw the same thing as before. While doing this you might miss the finishing of the update step, which in the end causes lower than optimal framerate.

(Remember drawing the exact same picture as before doesn't benefit anyone).

Comment: This is actually incorrect. What you do is you keep track of the time since the last update during each render, and any objects with velocity are positioned by a linear progression. This allows you to give yourself much more breathing room in the update (say, if you have complex AI) and not cramp your precious 60 fps.

Comment: @CodeBunny, in that case you don't have a clear separation between rendering and updating, since the renderer needs to calculate (a temporary) logical next 'state' for all the objects next to the actual rendering. Complex AI is a totally different problem, here you use a separate thread to work out the AI, but have the update thread (not the render thread) use lineair progression every update, until the actual position state is corrected by the multi-frame-separate-thread AI task.

Answer (score 0):

I've made my program using three threads (though more could be used).

1. Update logic (Does the data collecting and pre-processing)
2. Helper thread (Calculates time consuming cache pre calculations etc. at infinite sleep 1ms loop ... So this thread does not care where Update logic is going, or how fast. It just checks where it is going and calculates iF it needs to cache new items)
3. Render thread (Does ONLY rendering, everything it needs to render is pre-processed so it does only draw functions and calculates screen positions)

Doing this is super easy if you just have "thread safe" items you are drawing. But in game, I personally think that it is not bad thing if you render player 1 one tick ahead than player 2... Because you still want to draw as fast you can on games. Game logic thread makes sure there is no logical exceptions... So usually I think it does not matter what you draw and when, you just do it as fast as you can without thinking any "synchronizations".

I presonally prefer `public static volatile item` to share data between threads. And `AtomicIntegerArray` is a useful class for that too.

Answer (score 0):

I would say add a field that specifies the thread needed to run and render, and number the threads, if the thread number == the thread required, then it is allowed to run and render, and increment the required thread field, until it hits max, then loop back to 0. Alternatively, you could, use one thread for tick and another for render, this might be easier. Here is an example code:

```
public Game() {
    this.tickThread=new Thread(this::tickLoop());
    this.renderThread=new Thread(this::renderLoop());
}
public void tickLoop() {
    //code for timing...
    while(running) {
        //more code for timing...
        tick();
    }
}
public void renderLoop() {
    //code for timing or syncing frames...
    while(running) {
        //more code for timing...
        render();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could say:

---

|MyRunnable.java|

```
public interface MyRunnable
{
    public abstract void run(boolean toRender);
}
```

---

|MyThread.java|

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    private boolean isRender;
    private MyRunnable runnable
    public MyThread(boolean isRender,MyRunnable runnable)
    {
        this.isRender=isRender;
        this.runnable=runnable;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        this.runnable.run(this.isRender);
    }
}
```

---

|Game.java|

```
public class Game extends /*JPanel/Canvas/JFrame/Some other component*/
{
    private MyThread tickThread;
    private MyThread renderThread;
    private boolean running;
    public Game()
    {
        super();
        tickThread=new MyThread(this::run);
        renderThread=new MyThread(this::run);
        //other constructor code
    }
    public void tick()
    {
        //tick code here
    }
    public void render()
    {
        //render code here
    }
    public void run(boolean isRender)
    {
        //timing variables
        while(running)
        {
            //timing code
            if(isRender)
            {
                this.render();
            }
            else
            {
                this.tick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```